# Problema bindParam en INSERT con bucle según JSON

Tags: php, pdo, foreach, insert

Tengo un web service, en el que recibo un JSON que contiene una serie de lugares.

El JSON que recibo es correcto (lo compruebo con una función que valida JSON), entonces lo meto en un array:

```
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
$obj = json_decode($json);
```

Después hago un bucle, recorriendo ese array, para ejecutar los insert:

```
    $sql = $bdd->prepare('INSERT INTO progreso (progreso.id, progreso.ubicacion, progreso.nombre) SELECT bcficha.id, bcficha.ubicacion, bcficha.nombre FROM bcficha WHERE bcficha.ubicacion
= :lugar');
    
    foreach ( $obj as $sala )
    { 
        $sql->bindParam(':lugar', $sala);
        $sql->execute();
        
        echo $sql->queryString."<br>";
    }
```

Y una de las consultas que se ejecuta es:

> INSERT INTO progreso (id, ubicacion, nombre) SELECT id, ubicacion,
> nombre FROM bcficha WHERE ubicacion = :lugar

Es decir, no me está sustituyendo la variable del array en la consulta PDO, ¿Alguien ve los errores?

Gracias.Un saludo.

Comment: Proba agregando esto dentro del bucle a ver si te da un error `echo '<pre>', print_r($sql->errorInfo());`

Comment: lo añadí, este es el resultado: {<pre>Array
(
    [0] => 00000
    [1] => 
    [2] => 
)
1}

Comment: Es importante verificar en cada iteracción del bucle el valor que adquiere `$sala`, pues puede que en algún caso produzca un dato duplicado o algo así, lo cual hará que la consulta falle. De todos modos el planteamiento de tu pregunta no es claro, dices por ejemplo que *una de las consultas que se ejecuta es*, en realidad, siempre se ejecuta **la misma consulta**. Incluso, este tipo de inserciones en bucle en mejor hacerlas mediante transacciones. Otra cosa que falta en tu código es el control de errores, puede haber fallos de clave duplicada o de otra restricción.

Answer (score 1):

Tenés que especificar a qué tabla pertenecen las propiedades. Esto debido a que ambas tablas comparten el mismo nombre en ciertas columnas.

Y para el bucle lo mejor es preparar la consulta fuera del bucle en sí y dentro vincular las variables y ejecutar la consulta.

Algo así debería quedarte:

```php
    $sql = $bdd->prepare('INSERT INTO progreso (progreso.id, progreso.ubicacion, progreso.nombre) SELECT bcficha.id, bcficha.ubicacion, bcficha.nombre FROM bcficha WHERE bcficha.ubicacion = :lugar');
    foreach ( $array as $ubicacion => $sala )
    { 
        $sql->bindParam(':lugar', $sala);
        $sql->execute();
    }
```

Comment: Gracias por tu aporte, cambié a tu código y está es una de las consultas que hace a la bbdd --> 'INSERT INTO progreso (progreso.id, progreso.ubicacion, progreso.nombre, progreso.evacuacion,progreso.prioridad) SELECT
bcficha.id, bcficha.ubicacion, bcficha.nombre,bcficha.evacuacion, bcficha.prioridad FROM bcficha WHERE bcficha.ubicacion
=
:lugar'

Comment: sigue sin sustituir el valor de la variable lugar

Comment: @wiki te fijaste en la BD si subió los datos?

Comment: si comprobé la BBDD, no realizó la consulta. Estoy probando con bindValue() pero tampoco da resultado

Comment: @wiki en el `WHERE` puse `bcficha.ubicacion` no sera que es de la otra tabla? Si no es de bcficha cambialo por `progreso.ubicacion`.

Comment: es de la tabla bcficha, la consulta es correcta, de hecho si la copio y la pego en SQL my admin, cambiando :lugar la ejecuta. El problema es que el bindparams no mete el valor de $sala en la consulta, y por tanto la consulta la hace con bcficha.ubicacion=:lugar